# Angular - notyfing on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am build a site navigation with components, it's like this:

```
<site-wrapper>
  <site-header>
    <site-menu />
  </site-header>
  <site-section />
  <site-section />
</site-wrapper>
```

And now, my `site-wrapper` is like this:

```
class siteWrapperController {
  $onInit() {
    this.sections = [];
  }

  addSection(section) {
    if (this.sections.indexOf(section) === -1) {
      this.sections.push(section);
    }
  }
}

app.component('siteWrapper', {
  controller: siteWrapperController,
  template,
  transclude: true
});
```

and my `site-section`:

```
class siteSectionController {
  $onInit() {
    const id = this.sectionId;
    const title = this.sectionTitle;
    this.o = { id, title };
    this.wrap.addSection(this.o);
  }
}

app.component('siteSection', {
  template,
  transclude: true,
  controller: siteSectionController,
  bindings: {
    sectionTitle: '@',
    sectionId: '@'
  },
  require: {
    wrap: '^siteWrapper'
  }
});
```

What I am basically doing here it that I am registering each section within wrapper in its `sections` array. Now I want to pass that `sections` to `site-menu`:

```
class siteMenuController {
  $onInit() {
    this.buildSections(this.wrap.sections);
  }

  buildSections(sections) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(sections, s => {
      console.log(s);
    });
  }
}

app.component('siteMenu', {
  controller: siteMenuController,
  bindings: {
    items: '<',
    className: '@'
  },
  template: template,
  transclude: true,
  require: {
    wrap: '^siteWrapper'
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, it returns empty. Which means, this is running too early. I could just throw `setTimeout` there and be done with, but I believe there is a better way. I am hoping to omit `$scope` and `$broadcast/$emit` and just have the components talk to each other somehow ;-)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can put watch on variable that will be executed whenever value of variable changes

for example if your variable is $scope.newVar

then you can put watcher on it

```
$scope.$watch('newVar',function(newval,oldval){
 //your code goes here
})
```

Comment: I dont' want to use `$scope`, this isn't the best practice in ng1.5